# Unable to reference custom metadata type while creating 2GP managed package. Visibility of custom metadata is set to package protected

Tags: custom-metadata

I am creating a 2GP managed package, wherein I have a custom metadata object with name cred__mdt. I am quering this metadata from apex. My app is an LWC component which communicates with external system. Overall app is working absolutely fine until its time for creating version using

`force:package:version:create`

When I run this command from my CLI I am getting multiple errors related to custom metadata type

> operateOnComp: Invalid type: Cred__mdt

Visibility of this custom metadata is set as Package protected in dev-ed org.

Please explain how to include custom metadata in 2GP managed package with all its fields and with no record, because subscriber needs to create their own record there.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. We need specific technical detail; here, things like the `sfdx-project.json`, the folder structure for your package directory (specifically showing where the CMT and LWC are defined) and the command you are using to create a package version.